# Is there any possible way to load test WOWZA Cloud Live streaming video?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter to test load /performance of live streaming severs including WOWZA live streaming engine. But I am unable to test Live streaming of **WOWZA cloud**, since I am getting a lot of Time out errors. I am very well aware that the timeout is not because of the delay in response because the live streaming is running smoothly when opened from an external network. I found out that, after some period of load request being send to Wowza cloud, the domain name itself is getting changed(its dynamic). I have created the config in jmeter in such a way that all the URL path, Playlist.m3u8, chunklist.m3u8, and corresponding stream(ts) files  are dynamic. But, since the domain name itself is getting changed after a period of load test, the request sending are partially getting failed(maybe because the domain name which I am sending request is not responsible to handle all the requests anymore). **Can anybody suggest what to do? And is there any way to test load in WOWZA cloud?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are testing a multi-tenant cloud environment the first thing you must do is get permission from Wowza.  Almost all Cloud applications have restrictions on the use of automation outside of their published interfaces.  Your point of contact inside of Wowza will work with you for your testing window, scale, approve your performance test plan, your pacing and think times to ensure that they are reasonable and will not impact their service to other tenants on the system.

They can also provide technical insight on how to construct your tests given some unique features/capabilities/engineering for the site.  They may even be able to provide you with sample code.

As a general rule of thumb, you don't point and fire tactical nuclear software at sites you don't own, manage, control or have direct written permission from those that do have those rights.

Comment: Hi @James Pully , Thanks for your valuable feedback. I really appreciate your prompt reply on this. This was actually an eye opener. Actually, I had a meeting with the director of WOWZA and I got the permission. As per him, the wowza cloud cannot be load tested at all. So wanted to give a try. By the way it does not make any sense to load test on a scaling cloud server.

Comment: It makes sense to load test on a scaling cloud server. It's not because it's on cloud that it scales and your performances will be ok. Performance testing the service will help ensuring it can handle the expected audience with good performance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this JMeter [plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/performance-testing-wowza-streaming-server/).

It is a plugin that will do URL extraction automatically from manifest without you needing to use JMeter [extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), as a consequence even when segment’s URLs will change due to Wowza Cloud scaling, this will be taken into account.

Besides, it will accurately similate how player request the server and give metrics on User Experience.

Still as written by the other answer ensure you:

- ask for authorization to avoid your test being marked as DDOS
- ensure you disable Java DNS caching for JMeter's JVM

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops it.